What type of DC connector is this for a Cisco 8961 phone?
I have a Cisco 8961 VOIP phone that uses a PWR-CUBE-4 power supply.
Somehow its DC connector got messed up. I want to just replace that, but I was not able to identify or find anything like it. Searches on google didn't get me anything.

Here is the socket on the back of the phone:


Have you tried IdentiConn?

@winny some of them are similar but their center pin is too thick, or their diameters do not match.

Worst case, Cisco is big enough to have custom made the connector to make your life harder, but calling @DavideAndrea just be make sure. He should beam in any minute now.

That is a 3-circuit coaxial barrel power coupler.
My Identiconn utility identifies it as a Same Sky PJ-097H (jack) and PP-065574-M (plug).
Digikey sells the plug: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/same-sky-formerly-cui-devices/PP-065574-M/12822248

Can I ask what did you search that got you the answer?

#Abol_Fa First, I knew the general class of components: "coaxial barrel power". Then, I used my Identiconn utility, and went to that class. Then, I noticed that your connector had three circuits, so I used the filter and selected 3 circuit. The utility listed 8 possibilities. I scanned them and saw a picture that matched your pictures.

Get a used supply off eBay or another platform. Make sure it's genuine. It doesn't need to be working, since you just want to cut half of the cable with connector on it and solder it to the existing, working supply's output cable.
